# How to prevent modal event listener from affecting other items?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a Library app where a user can track unread and read books. I have it setup where when you click a book a modal pops up with the title, author, and buttons allowing you to mark the book as read or completely delete it.

I'm trying to fix a problem where opening and closing more than one modal and then clicking the delete button will delete all the items you previously clicked.

Here's the delete function -

```
Book.prototype.delete = function() {
  myLibrary = myLibrary.filter((e) => {
    return e !== this;
  });
};
```

Here's how I'm opening each modal -

```
const render = () => {
  const booksUnreadList = document.getElementById('unread');
  const booksReadList = document.getElementById('read');

  booksUnreadList.innerHTML = 'Unread';
  booksReadList.innerHTML = 'Read';

  myLibrary.forEach((book) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'book';

    book.read === 'Read'
      ? booksReadList.appendChild(li)
      : booksUnreadList.appendChild(li);

    li.innerHTML = book.info();
    li.addEventListener('click', function handler() {
      openBookModal(book);
    });
  });
```

And then the modal itself -

```
function openBookModal(book) {
  document
    .getElementById('book-modal-mark-complete')
    .removeEventListener('click', markReadHandler);
  document
    .getElementById('book-modal-delete')
    .removeEventListener('click', deleteHandler);

  bookForm.style.display = 'none';
  toggleForm.style.backgroundColor = '#978de0';
  toggleForm.innerHTML = 'Add Book';

  const bookModal = document.getElementById('book-modal');
  bookModal.style.display = 'grid';

  document.getElementById('book-modal-title').innerHTML = book.title;
  document.getElementById('book-modal-author').innerHTML = 'By ' + book.author;

  document
    .getElementById('book-modal-mark-complete')
    .addEventListener('click', markReadHandler);
  function markReadHandler() {
    book.read = 'Read';
    render();
    bookModal.style.display = 'none';
  }

  document
    .getElementById('book-modal-delete')
    .addEventListener('click', deleteHandler);
  function deleteHandler() {
    book.delete();
    render();
    bookModal.style.display = 'none';
  }

  document.getElementById('book-modal-close').addEventListener('click', () => {
    bookModal.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle of everything, to recreate the problem just open and close 2+ books and then delete 1 of them.
https://jsfiddle.net/Spawn_Bot/w6j4b8Lh/4/

Thanks!

Comment: Not a solution, but a notice - a modal does not open twice for the same book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the currently selected book in the `currentBook` variable, move the modal event handlers outside the `openBookModal()` function and in the event handlers you could delete the `currentBook`:

```
let currentBook = {};

...

function openBookModal(book) {
    currentBook = book;
    ...
}
document
  .getElementById('book-modal-mark-complete')
  .addEventListener('click', markReadHandler);

function markReadHandler() {
  currentBook.read = 'Read';
  render();
  bookModal.style.display = 'none';
}

document
  .getElementById('book-modal-delete')
  .addEventListener('click', deleteHandler);

function deleteHandler() {
  currentBook.delete();
  render();
  bookModal.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Here's the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k6z08m2q/